# Save video in React Native App and play if phone net is off

Tags: react-native

I want to play a video when the phone net is off. I am using *react-native-video* library for play the video. But now I want if phone net is off then the video should play offline, same like WhatsApp video play if net is off. Before play offline I need to save this in our local app.

Any suggestion on how I can achieve this functionality.

Comment: Expo File System is a good place to look for downloading files to the phone for offline use: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400537/react-native-video-how-to-save-a-video

Comment: Please elaborate more are you trying for single video or multiple videos and if multiple then it will be changed or same?

Comment: it will be multiple video